# Shall I localise and translate Schema.org structured data into each available language?

Tags: schema.org, multilingual, internationalization, json-ld

Let's say we have a website that is offered in English and German. Assume the Services offered  -

```json
{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Service",
"serviceType": "#{t('TRANSLATION.MARKETING')}",
"provider": {
"@type": "LocalBusiness",
"name": "#{Settings.brand.company_name}"
}
```

-- are available in UK, Ireland, Germany, Austria and beautiful Switzerland (hence, content is available in both EN & DE).

Should we add the structured data both on EN & DE pages in English, or shall we translate it into each respective language?

Example - Translated JSON-LD with LocaleApp (Ruby on Rails):

```json
"areaServed": [
{
"@type": "Country",
"name": "#{t('generals.united-kingdom')}"
},
"@type": "Country",
"name": "#{t('generals.ireland')}"
},
"@type": "Country",
"name": "#{t('generals.austria')}"
},
"@type": "Country",
"name": "#{t('generals.germany')}"
},
"@type": "Country",
"name": "#{t('generals.switzerland')}"
},
]
```

or just keeping it simple and tag in English (on both EN & DE):

```json
"areaServed": [
{
"@type": "Country",
"name": "United Kingdom"
},
"@type": "Country",
"name": "Ireland"
},
"@type": "Country",
"name": "Germany"
},
"@type": "Country",
"name": "Austria"
},
"@type": "Country",
"name": "Switzerland"
},
]
```

I am split about this, given the information is for search engines, and to make sense of the content (Semantic Web). Of course anything tagged on a page needs to correspond to its content (according to Google Best Practice). However, JSON-LD remains something we feed to SEs and not the user. So by that logic, offering it in English should be sufficient. I have not been able to find a clear answer to this.

So if anyone has a link that confirms the best practice that would be amazing - or perhaps has experience with multilingual pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Guide **[Managing multi-regional and multilingual sites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192)** tells us:

> **Use different URLs for different language versions**
>
> Google recommends using different URLs for each language version of a
> page...

This means that your versions for English and German content must have separate URLs.

Another Google guide **[Follow the structured data guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#relevance)** tells us the following:

> **Relevance**
> Your structured data should be a true representation of the page
> content.

Thus, your structured data for separate web pages in English and German must have content in the language of the content of the web page to which this data refers.

Added ***2019-10-01*** due to the new user question:

> I may display user content as country "Österreich", while structured
> data says "Austria".

Check the following information for the **[addressCountry](https://schema.org/addressCountry)** property of Schema:

> The country. For example, USA. You can also provide the two-letter ISO
> 3166-1 alpha-2 country code.

Use the name and alternate name properties for your country data. For country identifiers, use the property **[additionalProperty](https://schema.org/additionalProperty)** and the embedded type **[PropertyValue](https://schema.org/PropertyValue)**. E.g.:

```
> "@type":"Country", 
> "name":"Austria", 
> "sameAs":[
> "http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/1000062",
> "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austria",
> "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreich" ], 
> "alternateName":[
> "Republic of Austria", 
> "Österreich", 
> "Republik Österreich" ],
> "additionalProperty":{
> "@type":"PropertyValue", 
> "unitCode":"AT",
> "sameAs":[ 
> "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:AT",
> "http://dbpedia.org/page/ISO_3166-2:AT" ] }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - partially, I agree with what you are saying; however, in terms of relevance - Google refers to the content, but not the language. I may display user content as country "Österreich", while structured data says "Austria". It still contains the same content, yet in two different languages. Besides, how do I know for sure that Google can cope with translated data - i.e. country. Perhaps the developers assume it to be in English? And that's precisely what I want to have answered. In black and white - yes you can translate or no - keep it in English.